# Horizontally align two views using Auto Layout in IB

Tags: cocoa, autolayout, interface-builder

I have a radio button and a label. I need to have them aligned horizontally in an NSView, such that the radio button is to the left of the label: 
[Radio Button] [Label]

This seems a pretty trivial thing to do, but when do it in IB, I end up with the Label on top of (or maybe under) the button. If I instead programmatically apply constraints, I get precisely what I want. Here are the programatic constraints:

```
[self  addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
                            constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-5-[_deviceButton][_statusLabel]-20-|"
                                    options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBottom
                                            metrics:nil views:views]];
```

In IB, I use "Trailing Space to Container", "Top Space to container" "Bottom Space to container", "Leading space to Container" for both views and I set a "Horizontal Spacing" constraint between the two views. What could I be missing in IB? I've done this before, but can't for the life of me get it right?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want the group of both buttons to be centered inside your view.

In that case, embed the two items in a view (select them, then go to Editor > Embed In > Custom View), then you can center that container view horizontally in your view.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want all four of those constraints for *both* elements. Your button, which you want to be the leftmost of the two views, should be constrained to its container on the top, *leading*, and bottom; the label should be constrained to its container on the top, *trailing*, and bottom. The constrain the button's right edge horizontally to the label's left. (You'll notice that that's exactly what your visual format winds up generating.)